# React instrumentation encountered an error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - while trying to fetch a big amount of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a React app that presents a list of products. The total amount of products in the database is over 12,000.

## My Goal

When a user is filtering by name or changing the amount of products being shown on a single page, I want to show a Loading component while fetching the data from the server.

### My Execution

The component's state has a property `isFetching` that defaults to false.
When using the filter, the function `setFilterBy` is being called and by using setState it sets the filter to the current filterBy and the `isFetching` to true. setState's callback function is calling the function `loadProducts`. After `loadProducts` gets the products from the server it resets `isFetching` back to false.

```
 setFilterBy = (filterBy) => {

      this.setState((prevState) => {

        if (filterBy.term || filterBy.limit) {
          filterBy.page = 0;
        }
        return {
          isFetching: true,
          filterBy: {
            ...prevState.filterBy,
            ...filterBy,
          },
        };
      }, this.loadProducts);
  };

loadProducts = async () => {
    const results = await ProductService.loadProducts(this.state.filterBy);

    if (results) {
      const { products, rowCount } = results;
      this.setState({ ...this.state, products, rowCount, isFetching: false });
    }
  };
```

The Loading component is being rendered conditionally by the `isFetching` property.

```
render() {
const { products, isFetching } = this.state;

const listDisplay = !products ||  isFetching ? (
      <Loading />
    ) : (
      <ProductList products={products} />
    );

 return (
      <div className="product-page-container main-layout-container">
        <div className="product-top-bar">

          <ProductLimit setFilterBy={this.setFilterBy} />
          <ProductFilter
            filterBy={this.state.filterBy}
            setFilterBy={this.setFilterBy}
          />
        </div>

        {listDisplay}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now usually it's fast enough to not even show the loading component, so to check it I slow down my network and it works fine. **Unless** I'm trying to set the page limit to 'All', which gets all 12000+ products from the server.

## The Problem

When I set the limit to 'All' I get an Error saying:

[*Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB9gp.png)

I have looked everywhere and can't find the reason.
Does anybody have an idea for what is causing this issue?

Comment: do you have a didUpdate anywhere in the code?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman Nope, not on this component